# Use Facebook app access_token to get age-restricted Page data through Graph API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk, oauth-2.0, facebook-opengraph

I have a Facebook application that users can add to their Facebook business Page(s) as a Page Tab app. It doesn't require any extended permissions for the user. I'm wondering if it's possible to use my app access_token and make calls against the Facebook Graph API to retrieve information about age-restricted Pages?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, if a page is restricted demographically (e.g. for alcohol) you MUST use a user access token from a user who meets those restrictions, or a Page access token for the page itself.

An app access token will not work for such an API call

Comment: Is there any documentation for this?

Comment: No, it's implicit that if a user can't see something on Facebook, they also can't see it via the API; (and if you're not a user, you won't meet user-level restrictions)

Comment: What about permissions/restrictions in general? I'd like to know what permissions a facebook page/user/etc can have (logged-in required, above 18, must be friends, must be in the same group/network, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

If the owner of that access token can view the data on facebook you can get any data using that access token not mater if its block for the others .