# get campaigns info from facebook marketing api in C#

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api, .net-core, facebook-marketing-api

Hope I will get some help and not get marked as duplicate because spent a couple of days and still didn't find a solution for this one.
My problem is that I am working on an application that should get data from Facebook marketing API and I didn't manage to do it and am working in C#, FE is in React but would like to do this all on BE.
I created an app on Facebook, have appId, app secret, my client Id, accountId, set business manager and realize that one way to go is to go through app review but this is not an option because there are too many clients and it is not the best scenario.

Is there any other way that I implement fully user authentication, to first get authorization code and then user access token so I could get the data I need.
If I get the code over the browser I can generate a token but I would like to do it automatically over my code.
If I call https://www.facebook.com/v9.0/dialog/oauth?client_id=%7Bapp_id%7D&redirect_uri=%7Bredirect_uri%7D over httpClient it gives back some HTML text and I would need the URL it redirects you to in the browser (like on [facebook - how to get a new authorization code for an access token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18854812/facebook-how-to-get-a-new-authorization-code-for-an-access-token))
And didn't find a way access token without that authorization_code

Comment: 1. You need to submit your app for review, before it will be usable by normal Facebook users. 2. There is no way to perform user authentication, without user interaction.

Comment: That is what i thought but hoped that I could avoid this.
I went to "facebook login button option" and after user is logged in than send token to BE and get data. That is the most automated way to reduce my work per client. 
Thanks for comment.