# Facebook Graph API | Page feed

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am having a problem with the facebook graph API, when I try to read a Page feed using `graph../{pageId}/feed` it works only for some pages. On other pages I get the following error:

`{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#200) Requires extended permission: ads_management or manage_pages",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 200
  }
}`

Comment: is the page unpublished or restricted by age/location?

Comment: Yes its restricted by location, but I checked it with 2 accounts and from the 1st one it worked and the 2nd I got that error

Comment: what token are you using? app, user or page token?

Comment: I'm using user token

Comment: some pages are restricted to 18+ too, which affects whether you can access data via the API

Comment: alcohol restriction - although other types of pages can be 18+/adults only http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11747155/use-facebook-app-access-token-to-get-age-restricted-page-data-through-graph-api

Comment: I'm using 2 accounts to test it with the same configuration on age country and for the 1st it works and the 2nd it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

The Page is restricted by location, as we found out in the comments. If it works for one user, most likely the other one is not allowed to view the page - which means that you can´t grab the feed with his User Token. The Page could also be unpublished, but i guess that´s not the case.

If you are unsure, try lifting the restriction and test it.

If that does not work, you should file a bug.

Comment: I'm using 2 accounts to test it with the same configuration on age country and for the 1st it works and the 2nd it doesn't work

Comment: something must be different then. add the second account as app admin, developer or tester and try again.

Comment: after that, try adding the second user as page admin too. make sure you got the exact same state.

Comment: I don't have the possibility to do any changes in these pages. I have noticed It does this sometimes when you have special permissions on the page like page_editor or page_admin. But the thing is I only ask for the /{pageId}/feed

Comment: why do you want to use the feed of pages you don´t own? the best way to do that is by using a page token, and you can only get that one if you are admin of the page.

Comment: You can get any page feed with an `User Access Token` but as I described earlier in some pages (random) I get that weird error.

Comment: that´s not entirely true, you can´t get ANY page feed with a user token. if the page is restricted by age or location and the user does not fit the restriction, you can only get the feed with a page token.

Comment: I've been testing this with >300 pages and ~100 users and I have a problem with only 2 users and 5 pages. Over 100 pages have restriction and every `user access token` works. even for the 'problematic' users not all their pages produce this error. I've noticed that with graph 2.4 this error doesn't show up, only for 2.3

Comment: of course it works with a user token, IF the user is allowed to see the page content.

Comment: if you are unsure about the error, you should file a bug on facebook. if it works with v2.4 but not with v2.3, it may be one.